# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies. Either include them or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, use-effect

When I load my React application, I get this warning:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.maxEast',
> 'props.maxNorth', 'props.maxSouth', and 'props.maxWest'. Either
> include them or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I've been unable to find a solution that removes this warning. The four props above are props of the Map component for which this useEffect function resides. The useEffect function draws a bounding box on the map when the user performs a search in the application.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map.current) return; // wait for map to initialize

    // Check if Mapbox GL styles have loaded
    var check = checkIfMapboxStyleIsLoaded(map.current);
    if(check) {
      console.log("A load event occurred!");
      if(props.show) {
        map.current.addSource('newroute', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'properties': {},
          'geometry': {
          'type': 'LineString',
          'coordinates': 
            [
              [props.maxEast, props.maxNorth],
              [props.maxEast, props.maxSouth],
              [props.maxWest, props.maxSouth],
              [props.maxWest, props.maxNorth],
              [props.maxEast, props.maxNorth]
            ]
          }
        }
        });
          
        // Draws bounding box
        map.current.addLayer({
          'id': 'newroute',
          'type': 'line',
          'source': 'newroute',
          'layout': {
          'line-join': 'round',
          'line-cap': 'round'
          },
          'paint': {
          'line-color': '#ff0000',
          'line-width': 5
          }
        }); 
  
      }
      else if (map.current.getLayer('newroute')) {
        map.current.removeLayer('newroute');
        map.current.removeSource('newroute');
      }
    }
  }, [props.show]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, use effect expecting possible state and props variable as it dependency array, because it has eslint rules defined for it.

useEffect is sensing that you have many props variable but you only using 1 (props.show) in dependency array. That why it is suggesting warning to add all or remove them.

**Solution**

*

**1- Either add all of the props in the dependancy array like [props.show, props.hide ... etc]**

*

***2- Or you can just ignore this warning by adding this line before dependancy array***

```
useEffect(()=>{

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
},[props.show])
```

Answer (score -2):

You attache your UseEffect() with a props instead of attache it with a State value.

For fire the UseEffect() event, you need to attach it with a State like this :

```
[show, setShow] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {

   // do stuff
}, [show]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to remove the warning message.

Comment: Why he can't props.show?. We can absolutely add props in dependency array

Comment: Ok I didn't know you can do this. I thought you alway need to use state in dependency array