# Why I'm getting "Not Found: /api/products/undefined" instead of /api/products/1?

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework

I want to get data of a single product from "api/products/id" (I'm using Django Rest Framework) and put them into redux store, so when I refresh product's page the data will be actually displayed.
The problem is, *when I go to "localhost:3000/products/1" (I'm using also React) instead of getting product with id = 1, I get undefined product and no data at all*. The deeper point I've found where id is undefined is in views.py

Why this problem occurs? It has some connection with migration? I deleted database *.pyc + *.py files except init and then once again run makemigrations and migrate but nothing changed.

And how can I solve it?

**Browser's consol:**
[image: Browser's consol]

**VS Code terminal**
[image]

**EDIT - added front-end**
So if the problem is with front-end, then it should be probably during fetching. The request URL seems good to me and I don't see misspelling.
In fetchSingleProduct is only part of the url. The other part is set in package.json as a: `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",`

**singleProductSlice**

```
const initialState = {
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
    product: {
        reviews: [],
    }
}

const singleProductSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'singleProduct',
    initialState,
    reducers: {

    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchSingleProduct.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = "loading"
            })

            // I've fetched the data! I will add them to current state
            .addCase(fetchSingleProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                if(action.payload.message) {
                    state.status = "failed"
                    state.error = action.payload.message
                } else {
                    state.status = "succeeded"
                    state.product = action.payload
                }
            })
    }

})

// Fetch details about particular product, so when we refresh 
// page about particular product we won't have to depend on data from
// higher level component
export const fetchSingleProduct = createAsyncThunk('products/fetchSingleProducts', async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message
    }

})

export default singleProductSlice.reducer

export const selectSingleProduct = state => state.product
```

**ProductScreen.js**

```
// This is component that display data of a single product
function ProductScreen() {
    const productId = useParams().id    // I get id of the product
    console.log("Product id: ", productId)
    const product1 = useSelector(selectSingleProduct)   // I'm searching for pro
    console.log("Product: ", product1)
    // I created empty product so there will be less errors until solving the problem
    const product = {  
        reviews: []
    }

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const status = useSelector(state => state.singleProduct.status)

    useEffect((productId) => {
        // If client doesn't have any data from server...
        if(status === 'idle') {
        // ...fetch for this data
            dispatch(fetchSingleProduct(productId))
        }
    }, [status, dispatch])
```

**App.js**

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
   <Route path='/products/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
</Routes>
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):

    print("\n\n\nPlural key: ", pk) # The pk is undefined
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk) # So the product also is undefined
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    # ID is generating automatically
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              default='/placeholder.png')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    numReviews = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    countInStock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes, name='routes'),
    path('products/', views.getProducts, name='products'),
    path('products/<int:pk>', views.getProduct, name='product'),
]
```

Originally was `<str:pk>` but it throwed ValueError, so changed to `<int:pk>`.

Comment: are you sure its not your front-end problem? undefined is usually a JS thing and the reason that you got value error on <str:pk> is because django tried to get the product with ID of undefined.

Comment: @Mojtaba I'm not sure. I've thought that  it occurs in the front-end because it occurs in backend. I will edit post to show also code from front-end.

Comment: Could you please add the code of the frontend here?

Comment: @Metalgear I already added the code below images of the consoles

Comment: Where did you call the `createAsyncThunk` function?

Comment: @Metalgear Oh, I'm sorry. I called it in useEffect in ProductScreen.js. I will edit post once again so you can see it

Comment: I'm not an expert in js or reactjs bus it seems that fetchSingleProduct is not getting the product_id. before fetching from backend try to log product_id in console there and see what happends. (before this part of code try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`))

Comment: @Mojtaba Also get "undefined" so it seems you are right - fetchSingleProduct is not getting product_id. But why? I passed it wrong in useEffect?

Comment: I changed code a little bit, now `productId` is not passed as an argument to function inside `useEffect` and now I get the object! I have to change code yet to see if there won't be any issues. But why passing argument to the arrow function inside useEffect worked like this?

Comment: Okay everything works fine. Thank you a lot for help! ^^

Comment: sorry but as I said I'm not an expert on react and don't know how useEffect works. but you can ask it as another question and I'm sure someone can explain it and make things clear. hope it helps.

Comment: @Skafil can I post it as an answer? and maybe later you could update it as what was going wrong?

Comment: @Mojtaba, Sure! After I complet my research I will add a coment below your answer, why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Back-end code seems fine.
what I believe is happening is that your front-end (`fetchSingleProduct` function) is not getting the product id that it needs.

---

### Update from the OP.

**The reason** why it is not getting the product id is because in `useEffect` **"productId" is passed as an argument to arrow function**. But since this function is never called outside its declaration, the arrow function doesn't get any id, so **it gets "undefined"** instead.

To solve this, please remove "productId" argument from arrow function. The code will work after this, but there will be warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'productId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

To get ride of it, just pass "productId" to the array, that is `useEffect`'s second argument.
For details check: [React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies. Either include them or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802639/react-hook-useeffect-has-missing-dependencies-either-include-them-or-remove-the)

The `useEffect`'s code after changes will look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        // If client doesn't have any data from server...
        if(status === 'idle') {
        // ...fetch for this data
        dispatch(fetchSingleProduct(productId))
        }
    }, [status, dispatch, productId])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a problem in react. Please make sure the request API url is correct.
There is no problem in the backend side code.

Comment: I've checked it and don't see any issue there. Perhaps I'm passing somehow id in wrong way?